# Stack Overflow interaction error, other Stack Exchange sites unaffected

Tags: support, error-message

Ok, I've been fighting this for a while, but I'm going to have to submit to the greater wisdom of the community.

At work (where I do the vast majority of my coding) I can't do anything with SO except look at it. Any interaction with the site, such as commenting or voting causes a "An error occurred during comment submission" (or similar, red-box error) error. I'd like to be able to ask questions, up-vote useful posts, and generally participate in the site, so I tried all the standard bug fixes: clear-cache, disable add-ons, etc. Still no joy. I'm using IE10. I can't use any other browser.

This error is highly-reproducible, as it happens every time I try any interaction while at work. I can, however, use every other Stack Exchange site without issue.

The F12 Console error reads: `SCRIPT12045: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12045, The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect`. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you see what URL is causing the error (there should be a network section in the developer tools)?

Comment: Sounds like your office network is intercepting outgoing traffic. Try browsing the site over SSL instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are my person of the day. That did the trick. I can't believe it was that easy. You want to post that as an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your office network is filtering outgoing POST requests, it appears. This is usually caused by an overzealous web threat filter on a router.

Although still experimental, Stack Exchange sites *can* be accessed over SSL; change the `http://` to `https://` and your router or firewall will no longer be able to tell GET from POST, and cannot interfere and break your ability to comment, vote, or post.

Do note there are still [various bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl+bug+-status-completed) with the SSL support, but it is a viable work-around for your specific problem.

Comment: As mentioned above, you are a good person, and should feel good about yourself. Thanks!

Comment: However, because it's still in development, using SSL *may* cause other problems.